# Entity Framework Core - Thread Security and Context Locking by lock{}. Is my choose fine?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have API service endpoint built with gRPC. I have one class to implement database operations:

```
public SSImpl(BaseContext cnx)
        {
            this.cnx = cnx;

        }
```

Base context is

```
  public class BaseContext : DbContext
    {
        public BaseContext()

        {
            Database.EnsureDeleted();
            Database.EnsureCreated();

        }

        public DbSet<User> _Users { get; set; }

    }
```

I did it like this because i want to have easy switching between dev/prod version of application. So, in bigger part of my apps i used to `IDisposable` and magic `using(var con = new Context())` but now i have to inject context with his new type based on BaseContext to Database implementation class. So i used constructor like above, and i can use any context based on BaseContext.

```
InMemoryContext cnx = new InMemoryContext();
SQLiteContext sqlitecnx = new SQLiteContext();
SSImpl impl = new SSImpl(sqlitecnx);
SSImpl impl2 = new SSImpl(cnx);
```

Now i have problem with context usage. In testing i have exception

```
A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed.
```

and

```
"A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2097913.")'
```

So, my question and ideas are:

Is that better to use it like locking synchro operations

```
 lock (cnx)
            {

                cnx._Users.Add(new User
                {
                    Nick = nick,
                    Password = password,
                    Details = new UserDetails
                    {
                        Email = email
                    }

                });

                cnx.SaveChanges();
            }
```

To be sure that operation 1 is finished before operation 2 started, or maybe **I should use await `SaveChangesAsync` Instead of SaveChanges**? Im not sure, because now i cant use IDisposable context, and i dont know if `SaveChangesAsync` will do something like queue of db operations? If it do, what with Selects? Wouldn't it be conflictable? Or maybe i need to use separate contexts to Creating and Updating, and Reading?

Comment: It's wrong. DbContext is *not* thread-safe and doesn't need to be. It shouldn't be reused among requests. It represents a single Unit-of-Work, which is why it's almost always registered as a Scoped service in DI. *All* changes are saved when the code calls `SaveChanges` or `SaveChangesAsync` right before the DbContext is disposed. There's no reason to call `SaveChanges` multiple times

Comment: Check Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repositories and unit of work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) for more.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Okay, so my thinking way is wrong. I thought that this using of context is good idea, even found post from fan forum of asp.net that this DI is great idea. So ok, i understood your answer as i should back to IDisposable. So now i will change my classes. Thank you.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos great article, it should be your Answer on my Question. May help a lot of people.